# Java OutOfMemoryError on jetty server running JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jetty, out-of-memory, permgen

I'm facing a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` and subsequent `PermGen space` errors on my project environment.

The same code works for the others developers in my team and we wasn´t able to catch the main cause of the problem:

Here is part of the stack trace:

```
 [ERROR] /
 org.apache.tiles.request.render.CannotRenderException: JSPException including path '/web20/home/title.jsp'.
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:399)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:238)
    at org.apache.tiles.TilesContainerWrapper.render(TilesContainerWrapper.java:103)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.mgmt.CachingTilesContainer.render(CachingTilesContainer.java:126)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.DefinitionRenderer.render(DefinitionRenderer.java:59)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:145)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
...
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
    at com.xpto.catalog.home.filter.HomePageForwardFilter.doFilter(HomePageForwardFilter.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at com.xpto.web20.webcore.filter.NavAppContextFilter.doFilterInternal(NavAppContextFilter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
...
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:924)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: JSPException including path '/web20/home/title.jsp'.
    at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletUtil.wrapServletException(ServletUtil.java:61)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.jsp.JspRequest.doInclude(JspRequest.java:125)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractViewRequest.dispatch(AbstractViewRequest.java:47)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:45)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.render.ChainedDelegateRenderer.render(ChainedDelegateRenderer.java:68)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
    at org.apache.tiles.TilesContainerWrapper.render(TilesContainerWrapper.java:108)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:188)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.execute(InsertAttributeModel.java:132)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:299)
    at org.apache.jsp.web20.global.responsiveGlobalLayout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_insertAttribute_2(org.apache.jsp.web20.global.responsiveGlobalLayout_jsp:436)
...
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.forward(ServletRequest.java:265)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.doForward(ServletRequest.java:228)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractClientRequest.dispatch(AbstractClientRequest.java:57)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:45)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:397)
    ... 59 more
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
...
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.include(Dispatcher.java:192)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:1013)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:698)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.jsp.JspRequest.doInclude(JspRequest.java:123)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractViewRequest.dispatch(AbstractViewRequest.java:47)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:45)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.render.ChainedDelegateRenderer.render(ChainedDelegateRenderer.java:68)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
 [WARNING] EXCEPTION
 org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'systemErrorController' defined in class path resource [navapp-catalog-servlet-common.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.error(Dispatcher.java:135)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ErrorPageErrorHandler.handle(ErrorPageErrorHandler.java:129)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Response.sendError(Response.java:274)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:475)
...
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:924)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'systemErrorController' defined in class path resource [navapp-catalog-servlet-common.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:314)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.lookupHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:298)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1091)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:896)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    ... 30 more
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
 [ERROR] Nested in org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'systemErrorController' defined in class path resource [navapp-catalog-servlet-common.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space:
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'systemErrorController' defined in class path resource [navapp-catalog-servlet-common.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:314)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.lookupHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:152)
...
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.error(Dispatcher.java:135)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ErrorPageErrorHandler.handle(ErrorPageErrorHandler.java:129)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Response.sendError(Response.java:274)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:475)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:924)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
 [ERROR] Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'systemErrorController' defined in class path resource [navapp-catalog-servlet-common.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space:
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
 [ERROR] /shop/product/charter-club-damask-designs-geometric-dove-full-queen-comforter-set-only-at-xpto
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ProductDescriptionPageController' defined in class path resource [spring/navapp-catalog-context-common.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:314)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.lookupHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:298)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1091)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:896)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.xpto.web20.webcore.filter.NavappRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(NavappRequestFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.xpto.catalog.filter.xss.XssFilter.doFilter(XssFilter.java:64)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at com.xpto.web20.webcore.filter.NavAppContextFilter.doFilterInternal(NavAppContextFilter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.cj.trim.trimFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.xpto.nac.filters.TrimRESTFilter.doFilter(TrimRESTFilter.java:38)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:924)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
 [ERROR] Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ProductDescriptionPageController' defined in class path resource [spring/navapp-catalog-context-common.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space:
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
 [WARNING] EXCEPTION
 org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'systemErrorController' defined in class path resource [navapp-catalog-servlet-common.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.error(Dispatcher.java:135)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ErrorPageErrorHandler.handle(ErrorPageErrorHandler.java:129)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Response.sendError(Response.java:274)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:475)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:924)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'systemErrorController' defined in class path resource [navapp-catalog-servlet-common.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:314)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.lookupHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:298)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1091)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:896)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    ... 30 more
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
 [ERROR] Nested in org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'systemErrorController' defined in class path resource [navapp-catalog-servlet-common.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space:
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'systemErrorController' defined in class path resource [navapp-catalog-servlet-common.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:314)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.lookupHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:298)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1091)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:896)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
...
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

My code is synced with the master branch, I mean there isn't any difference between my code and the stable one...

Any clue? Is there any tool that I can use to help like a monitor (free one)?

Comment: Ask other dev what they have in their JAVA_OPTS, especially if they set the permanent generation space size suing -XX:PermSize  -XX:MaxPermSize

Comment: use java 8, no need for messing with permgen, and java 7 is EOLed

Comment: That stacktrace is truncated and doesn't indicate a memory error.  Can you edit your question to include the full stacktrace? Feel free to censor classnames that are proprietary.  *(Tip, for formatted sections in your question markup, use code sections, not quoted `>`, as it preserves the structure / formatting of things like stacktraces better)*

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I did the changes you asked for...

Comment: So spring was unable to allocate the memory to create a few beans.  And you are also using an **ancient** version of Jetty (seen by `org.mortbay.jetty` package space)  All of those Jetty versions were EOL (End of Life) about 6 years ago (and are likely incompatible with Java 8, as Jetty 9.2.0 was the first version with Java 8 support)